# To what extent does the anatomic location of a tendon injury impact the recovery time?

Tags: tendinopathy, recovery

{1} mentions:

> The healing potential of a torn or pathologic tendon varies depending on anatomic location (e.g., Achilles vs. rotator cuff) and local environment (e.g., intrasynovial vs. extrasynovial).

To what extent does the anatomic location of a tendon injury impact the recovery time?

---

References:

- {1} Thomopoulos, Stavros, William C. Parks, Daniel B. Rifkin, and Kathleen A. Derwin. "Mechanisms of tendon injury and repair." Journal of Orthopaedic Research 33, no. 6 (2015): 832-839. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4418182/ ; https://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2Fjor.22806

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to be asking us the question the study asked.